# VMWARE: For installing Visual Studio 2010 and connecting to it remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vmware-server, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion, vmware-player

I am trying to find a solution for installing Visual Studio 2010 (VMWARE) and connecting to it remotely so that both i can use the pc and the receiver can monitor what i am doing.

There seems to be so many different solutions for VMWARE and i am little of which will work.

It would be ideal if it was free of charge, i notice the "VMWARE PLAYER" is - but i think is only to run virtual machines???

If anybody has had any success of running VMWARE with visual studio 2010 i would look to hear your comments or any advice

Thanks

**EDIT**

TO clarify, i am looking to run visual studio 2010 in VM.

Comment: Are you looking to run VS2010 in a Virtual Machine (VM) or are you looking to use the debugging features of VS2010 to debug your app in a VM?

Comment: just running vs 2010 in a VM and connecting to it remotely... of course it needs to be able to do everything a normal install of vs 2010 does like debug launch application etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run VS2010 in VM you will need:

1. VMWare Server 2.0
2. Licenced operating system
3. VS2010

Follow those steps:

1. Install VMWare server on the physical host
2. Create a new virtual machine
3. Install operating system on your virtual machine
4. Install VS2010 + any other software you need for development
5. Connect your VM to internet so it can be connected to from internet (open necessary firewall ports)

*On a side note*: why do you want the receiver to have access to your development environment in the first place? Won't it suffice to give him access to your deliverables only? If you are developing a web site - publish it and give him access. For desktop apps give him the link to a site where you can dump your nightly builds...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jakub, but you could also use ESXi on a system do the same thing and have for a few trade shows I would do the following

1) VMware ESXi, use 4.01 located at [VMware vSPhere Hypervisor ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/)

2) Use Microsoft Windows 2008, you can be granted a 60 day license for testing.

3) Install Microsoft VS2010 (in my case it was Microsoft VS2008, its all our group uses.

The only issues I have found are when installing Visual Studio 2008, the OS detection might cause a few issues.   VS2010 should be able to correctly detect the OS you are using.

The other testing bed the developers I support use are based around the same thing, but use Xen for the hypervisor.  We have found on long haul networks using tunnels, VMware ESXi's remote console sessions can be crazy and produced odd graphical draws and even latency.

Good luck with Visual Studio 2010.  And I hope your teams work out.